# inline Constexpr const char* function in different headers

Tags: constexpr

I can define the following function in C++ header file and then include it in different .cc files.
I wonder whether compiler will always resort to the same str address, or it may be different, or it's undefined behavior?

```
inline constexpr const char *GetCompilerOptions() {
  return ""
  #ifdef __AVX__
         "AVX,"
  #endif  // __AVX__
  ;
}
```

Comment: Inlined variable's address will change for compilation unit. Consider creating a static variable instead.

Answer (score 0):

There's no magic here, inline is inline. `constexpr` doesn't change the situation.

In short, inlined functions is identical to copy pasting the body by hand. Thus, its address isn't guaranteed to be same. Most compilers will optimize to one address to save space (the optimization itself is allowed), though.

If you really need static address, you must make it static/global and put it in a dedicated source unit. Things in header isn't likely to have stable address.